# Google-app-script error invalid assignment left-hand side

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Hello I'm getting trouble to find this error in google apps script. I reviewed my code a bunch of time and nothing. This code is to use in a webhook in a service that work with inbound marketing which there I have some pop-up forms to get users for my newsletter, and I want this subscribers to my Mail chimp account just to send updates about blog. So I'm using this code below to do it, but I'm getting this error. Sorry If I code wrong.
The JSON source is like this https://github.com/ResultadosDigitais/rdocs/blob/master/rdstation_integration.json
the md5Hash function I create to give the hash of a string.

Thanks a lot if anyone could help me!

```
//receive the request
function doPost(e){
  return mcResponse(e);
}

//Send information to MC
function mcResponse(n){
  var email = n.parameter["leads[email]"];
  var nome = n.parameter["leads[name]"];
  var hash = md5Hash(email);

try {

  var bodyData = [];
  var mergeFields = ["FNAME" = nome];
  bodyData.push([
    "email_address" = email,
    "status_if_new" = "subscribed",
    "status" = "subscribed",
    "merge_fields" = mergeFields
  ]);

  var headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'apikey ' + API_KEY_MC
  };

 var options = {
   'method': 'PUT',
   'headers': JSON.stringify(headers),
   'payload': JSON.stringify(bodyData)
 };

 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(MC_URL + LIST_ID + '/members/' + hash, options);
 return ContentService.createTextOutput(response.getContentText());

 } catch(e){
   return ContentService.createTextOutput(e);
 }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but I wasn't able to find the details of the error in here. Are you able to provide them?

Comment: Please read the troubleshooting guide:  [Link to Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is caused by this line:

```
var mergeFields = ["FNAME" = nome];
```

Change it to:

```
var mergeFields = {"FNAME": nome};
```

Same for this code block:

```
bodyData.push([
  "email_address" = email,
  "status_if_new" = "subscribed",
  "status" = "subscribed",
  "merge_fields" = mergeFields
]);
```

Change it to

```
bodyData.push({
  "email_address": email,
  "status_if_new": "subscribed",
  "status": "subscribed",
  "merge_fields": mergeFields
});
```

Details about object literals in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#object_literals

Comment: Thanks a lot for your review! The changes that you suggest it was correct.